# TinyMCE: My HTML changes when saving the content. How can i keep my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, format

I am using the [formats paramter](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aformats) to initialize tinymce in order to use b-,i- and u-tags instead of spans and styles

```
formats: {
    bold : {inline : 'b' },  
    italic : {inline : 'i' },
    underline: { inline: 'u' }
},
```

When i save the content, the u-tags get replaced by spans (i- and b-tags are not affected):

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">underlined text</span>
```

**What can i do to keep my u-tags in the html?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some "try and error" i found a solution which works. But i am sure there is a more elegant way. Feel free to point me into the right direction. My solution consists of the replacement of the new span back to the u-tag on the onSave event:

```
ed.onSaveContent.add(function(ed, o) {
    o.content = o.content.replace(/<span style="text-decoration: ?underline;">(.*?)<\/span>/gi, "<u>$1</u>");   
});
```

Felix Risterer mentioned the [legacyoutput](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3alegacyoutput) plugin. It works with this plugin too, but i will stick with the solution above cause the legacyplugin does many things and i am not fully able to predict what else could be affected.

Comment: I was able to do replace for bold and italics in "elegant way":           extended_valid_elements : "b/strong,i/em" but that's probably not usable for spans with style attribute.